# How to delete self referencing entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

### Context

In my current project, there is a hierarchical folder structure saved in a database. The entity is the following:

```
public class Folder
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ParentFolderId { get; set; }
    public Folder ParentFolder { get; set; }
    public List<Folder> ChildFolders { get; set; } // Relationship property
    // Other properties
}
```

Only the root folder has null as `ParentFolderId`. All other folders have a non-null `ParentFolderId`. EFCore doesn't allow to set up cascade delete on `ParentFolderId`.

### Question

When a folder is deleted, I would like to delete all subfolders recursively as well. How can this be implemented?

### What I tried

In DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<Folder>()
        .HasOne(e => e.ParentFolder)
        .WithMany(e => e.ChildFolders)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);
}
```

Delete call:

```
public void DeleteFolder(string folderId)
{
    var folder = await _db.Folders
        .Include(d => d.ParentFolder)
        .Include(f => f.ChildFolders)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.Id == folderId);

    if (folder == null) return;
    if (folder.ParentFolderId == null) return null;

    _db.Folders.Remove(folder);
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, in this situation, I am only loading subfolders one level below in the hierarchy. I can call `ThenInclude` a bunch of times but cannot guarantee to have reached all subfolders.

Comment: You could recursively call `DeleteFolder` on the subfolders before deleting the main folder.  Or recursively get all the subfolders and then do one `RemoveRange`.

Comment: @juharr You are probably right. How do I do that, knowing only one folderId?

Comment: You've already got the `ChildFolders`, so you'd just loop on that and pass the ids to `DeleteFolder` or another method that would collect all the sub-folder ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it by including a method to get all the sub-folders.  The down side is this requires one select for each level of subfolders in the hierarchy.  The alternative would be SQL where you can write a recursive query to get all the ids to delete and then delete them.

```
public void DeleteFolder(string folderId)
{
    var folder = await _db.Folders
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.Id == folderId);

    if (folder == null) return;

    var foldersToDelete = await SubFolders(folder.Id);
    foldersToDelete.Add(folder);

    _db.Folders.RemoveRange(foldersToDelete);
    _db.SaveChanges();
}

public async Task<List<Folder>> SubFolders(string folderId)
{
    var subFolders = await _db.Folders
        .Where(d => d.ParentFolderId == folderId)
        .ToListAsync();

    var allFolders = new List<Folder>();
    foreach(var subFolder in subFolders)
    {
        allFolders.Add(subFolder);
        allFolders.AddRange(await SubFolders(subFolder.Id));
    }

    return allFolders;
}
```

Note this with run forever if you have any cycles in your folders (like folder A's parent is folder B and folder B's parent is folder A)

Comment: Great way to approach this problem. Thanks. In my code, I delete each child folder one by one at the end of the recursive function.

Comment: @M.Azyoksul There are variations on this that will work.  Some may be more performant than this and others not so I'd encourage you to test them out to see what works best.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing @juharr's answer a little bit. Instead of creating a bunch of lists, I create one list and pass its reference among the recursive function calls.

Here is my final code:

```
public void DeleteFolder(string userId, string folderId)
{
    var folder = await _db.Folders
        .Include(d => d.ParentFolder)
        .Include(f => f.ChildFolders)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.Id == folderId);

    if (folder == null) return;
    if (folder.ParentFolderId == null) return;

    var foldersToBeDeleted = new List<Folder>();

    folder.ChildFolders.ForEach(childFolder => PopulateSubFolder(childFolder.Id, foldersToBeDeleted));
    foldersToBeDeleted.Add(folder);

    _db.Folders.RemoveRange(foldersToBeDeleted);
    _db.SaveChanges();
}

private void PopulateSubFolder(string folderId, ICollection<Folder> foldersToDelete)
{
    var folder = _db.Folders
        .Include(f => f.ChildFolders)
        .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == folderId);

    if (folder == null) return;

    // Add child folders
    folder.ChildFolders.ForEach(subFolder => PopulateSubFolder(subFolder.Id, foldersToDelete));

    // Add current folder
    foldersToDelete.Add(folder);
}
```